# Existence and smoothness for viscous Burgers equation?

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, smoothness

What do we currently know about (references please!) the existence and smoothness of solutions to the viscous Burgers equation, in 1D, 2D, and 3D?

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to capitalize "Burgers". Viscous burgers sound really yucky.

Answer (score 1):

[Global existence and smoothness for solutions of viscous Burgers equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.01539) (2015).

> It is shown that the homogeneous viscous Burgers equation in $d$
>   spatial dimensions has a globally defined smooth solution if the
>   initial condition is a smooth function growing like $o(|x|)$ at
>   infinity.